# Title name to Process name in C#

Tags: c#

I want to find the name of a process through inputting the title of the program. For example, if I type "Google Chrome", I want the console to print "chrome" (how the process name looks in task manager) Thank you

Comment: The Process object has a property called MainWindowTitle which is likely the property you are referring to.  The System.Diagnostics namespace is where the Process objects are located.  You can then use Process.GetProcesses() to retrieve all of the processes running on your system. You then iterate through this list and look for one that has a window Title that matches the value you are looking for, break from the loop, and output the proc.ProcessName; foreach(Process proc in Process.GetProcesses()){ if(proc.MainWindowTitle == "Google Chrome"){ console.WriteLine(proc.ProcessName); break;}}

Comment: Why don't you write that as an answer @JohnBartels?

Comment: Of course, anything that allows multiple instances would either potentially return the wrong instance, or many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property in `Process` like in Task Manager Process Description, You can find the `FileDescription` of `EXE` by using `FileVersionInfo`

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();

foreach (var p in processes)
{
    try
    {
        var description = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(p.MainModule.FileName).FileDescription;
        if (description == "Google Chrome")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName);
            break;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // You will get Access is denied exception for some processes when accesses `MainModule`
    }
}
```

**Note : Run your application as Administrator**

Answer (score 0):

The Process object has a property called MainWindowTitle which is likely the property you are referring to. The System.Diagnostics namespace is where the Process objects are located. You can then use Process.GetProcesses() to retrieve all of the processes running on your system. You then iterate through this list and look for one that has a window Title that matches the value you are looking for, break from the loop, and output the proc.ProcessName;

```
foreach(Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
{ 
     if(proc.MainWindowTitle == "Google Chrome")
     { 
        Console.WriteLine(proc.ProcessName); 
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Might be simpler to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx GetProcessesByName(String)